# Error during Node startup/recovery in progress. Not yet ready to accept connections?

Tags: node.js, express, iisnode

I'm running an express server on IISNode, but noticed the web service is down due to:

I need to handle the exception which occurs during any crash of the system in IIS node due to configuration mismatch or connection problem.

```
I got the following error that Application has thrown an uncaught exception and it get terminated, not able to handle the exception:
 Error: Node startup/recovery in progress. Not yet ready to accept connections
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js:201:110)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at process._fatalException (node.js:224:26)
```

Looking at the error on Google. It looks like the error is coming from  a failed query to a vertica datatbase:

https://community.hpe.com/t5/Cloud-Optimizer-Practitioners/vPV-1-10-Error-Unable-to-collect-performance-data-from-data/td-p/6164633

**Question:**

How can I prevent IISNOde crashing on failed query?
Code to Handle the uncaught exception while IISNode Crashes.

These are my node dependencies in the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.1.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cors": "2.7.1",
    "cron": "^1.2.1",
    "express": "4.14.0",
    "mssql": "3.3.0",
    "winston": "2.2.0",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
  }
```

Comment: The issue was fixed a while. Can you install the latest iisnode and try again?    The test for it is at Ref: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/test/functional/www/116_configerror/web.config.

Comment: Can you reference which version you are referring to of `iisnode`? I don't see iisnode in my modules folder or package.json. but see it defined in web.config `<handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>`

Comment: Can you try adding/Replacing these lines in the "Web.Config"    <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <iisnode idontexist="12" />

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: is that worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the "Error: Node startup/recovery in progress." is that the IISNode older version has the bug which was crashing when the script tries to access the resources, which was fixed in the newer version of "IISNode".

In the following code mentioned, the line "`<iisnode idontexist="12" />`" take care of the fix and adding this following line of code will avoid the crash and handle the exception in IISNode.

This issue was fixed for a while,

Please install the latest "IISNode" and try again.

Can you try adding/Replacing these lines in the "Web.Config"

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="hello.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <iisnode idontexist="12" />

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Reference:
https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/test/functional/www/116_configerror/web.config